# Ungroup /Regroupe Shape VBA Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a new macro that Groupe and Ungroupe Shapes in Word in active document . 
I succeed with making it but I got a problem in grouping shapes again 
My code is

```
Private Sub degroupage_Click()
Dim mydocument As Document
Set mydocument = ActiveDocument
On Error Resume Next

ActiveDocument.Unprotect   'enregistré manuellement
Dim S As Shape, t As Shape

For i = 0 To mydocument.Shapes.Item(1).GroupItems.Count
For Each S In mydocument.Shapes
    If S.Type = msoGroup Then S.Ungroup
If S.Type = msoGroup Then S.Regroup

Next
Next

End Sub
```

Error : " Membre de méthode ou de données introuvable "
for   `S.Regroup`

I don't know what should I change

Thank you  in advance

Comment: You cannot `Regroup` a `Shape` object, that method is for the `ShapeRange` object. - see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shaperange-regroup-method-excel

Comment: I modified my code By  using this statement  ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Regroup  and now it Regroup all  the shapes in one page ,  what I want is regrouping shapes in that active page only

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246261/grouping-shapes-vba-word-macro

Comment: That's me again because I marked the answer of braX as solution  So i posted again for another question and problem