# Grouping shapes VBA word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to optimise my macro which allow me to ungroup all the shapes that are located in that active Page and if those shapes are already Ungrouped this macro will Group them

What I want to do is to modify this code to allow to group and Ungroup all  in the Active page only not all te document . I'm a little noobi with VBA 
this is my code

```
Private Sub degroupage_Click()
    Dim mydocument As Document
    Set mydocument = ActiveDocument
    On Error Resume Next

    ActiveDocument.Unprotect   'enregistré manuellement
    Dim S As Shape, t As Shape

    For i = 0 To mydocument.Shapes.Item(1).GroupItems.Count
        For Each S In mydocument.Shapes
            If S.Type = msoGroup Then S.Ungroup 'Ungrouping all shapes in all the document :(

            If S.Selection.Ungroup = True Then 
                ActiveDocument.Selection.ShapeRange.Regroup  ' Problem here
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I need a quick help
the error is  methode unfound for the `Regroup` and `S.Selection.Ungoup`

Comment: If someone could test it and help me with some solution and guidance

Comment: I realize there are times when "On Error Resume Next" may be appropriate, but I'm curious where your first error happens if you trap the errors? I get an error on the  "For i = 0 To....'

Comment: Problem start from line 10 If you delete  """" If S.Selection.Ungroup = True Then 
ActiveDocument.Selection.ShapeRange.Regroup"""   the macro Ungroup all shapes in the active document not in the active Page

Comment: You already execute an 'Ungroup' on line 9. As for line 10, there is no property or method of '.Selection'

Comment: I didn't find how to modify my code to Regroup shapes in Active Page if they are Ungroup ...... to verify if shapes are ungrouped then it will group them

Comment: I found solution  :D  but one last question how can groupe and Ungroupe shapes only in   '''''' Active Page"""" not " Active Document""" :D

Comment: I'm going to guess you would need to first find the 'Active Page', then possibly select a shape and somehow check if that shape is on the Active Page.

Comment: for ex I got  word with 5 page .... What I want is when I  switch between Pages I Group and Ungroup only the Active Page  ex 1 not 2 or 3